# Is there a way to do this in one step?

Tags: php, arrays

$clients = $CLIENT->find($options);
$client = $clients[0];

EDIT: I Realized i should be clearer. The $CLIENT->find always returns an array of objects, but I want one line of code that turns the array (that will only have 1 object) into just an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$client = array_shift($CLIENT->find($options));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$client = reset($CLIENT->find($options));
```

**Edit:** Here's a less obfuscated one, you should probably use this instead:

```
list($client) = $CLIENT->find($options);
```

They aren't identical though; the first one will also work in places where a single scalar is expected (inside a function's parameter list) but the second won't (`list()` returns void).

Comment: This does work, but I'd personally advise against using it. The purpose of the two lines of code in the question is a lot more clear than this condensed version.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `($CLIENT->find($options))[0]` works (IIRC I don't think it does in PHP, but don't take my word for it), I don't think you can condense that. I really don't think it's worth worrying about, though - if you need a one-statement expression for it, just write a function.

```
function fozzyle($options) {
    $clients = $CLIENT->find($options);
    return $clients[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$client = $CLIENT->find($options)[0];

doesn't work?

Comment: Not until now, that's the point. This will hopefully be fixed in PHP 6.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [method-chaining](http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html)?

This will allow you to do a lot with only one line of code. Note also that this would be better for larger and more long-term OO solutions. If you just need a quick and dirty solution, perhaps just a custom function that returns the first item in an array.

**Help:** If somebody can find a better reference for method-chaining, please update this.

Comment: this is an awesome solution, but yes- i was looking for quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0):

$client = array_shift($CLIENT->find($options));

$client will be your object or NULL if find() doesn't return anything.